# SQL Server making arithmetic abort enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.

In my stored procedures, I often have to call for XML data type, functions (like split).

Is it possible to permanently enable arithmentic abort for a database? I know it can be done using properties window > options but is there any script i can use to turn it on?

The reason to look for script is obvious; i have too many DBs to do it manually.

I assume `set arithabort off` and `set arithabort on` turns on arithabort only for the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As well as Marian's answer which is SQL Server Instance level, you can use [ALTER DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) to set it individually. You can also use it on the model database so that all new databases inherit the setting

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx), section "Considerations when to use Set options":

"The user options setting of sp_configure allows for server-wide settings and works across multiple databases. This setting also behaves like an explicit SET statement, except that it occurs at login time."

So you might want to look on the server system configuration procedure, [sp_configure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx).
It has an option called ["user options"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031.aspx), where you can configure some things at login time.

Your setting could be something like:

```
exec sp_configure 'user options', 64
go
RECONFIGURE 
go
```

Other helpful details can be found in this [forum thread](http://forums.databasejournal.com/showthread.php?t=7718) on DatabaseJournal.com.

Answer (score 2):

Hi There are default settings for ARITHMETIC ABORT AND ANSI_NULLS, etc at server level in 'Database Connection' Properties of the server in Management studio.

These are overridden by the individual settings of each database, which can be seen in the properties of each database - right click the db > properties > selection option on left hand side.

You should also consider that a number of client libraries will override both of these settings when connecting.